# Logging in to Facebook with GNU Icecat

Tags: firefox, facebook, icecat

I don't know if this is the right place, but: I've installed GNU Icecat, but whenever I try to log in to Facebook it tells me I have to enable cookies. I have enabled cookies (and third party cookies) in Icecat preferences. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: How did you install icecat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice Cat has an extension called LibreJS that doesn't allows proprietary javascript. Because of this you can't use facebook as it requires javascript to run. There are three solutions:

1. Use a different browser that does allow javascript
2. Whitelist facebook on LibreJS you probably will find it next to menu button

   [image]
3. Use a mobile friendly version of facebook. Like https://m.facebook.com/ you can use it from a pc don't need to be on a smartphone or tablet

Comment: You're right, the problem is with LibreJS. However, even after whitelisting facebook, it doesn't load properly, and the only way I've got it to load is to disable the plugin.